# REST API Query against Number on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to query a table against a "Number" field in parse using the REST API on iOS and AFNetworking to make the call. (I'm using REST API as it's a cross platform App and don't want to have to develop seperate API for each platform).

I can query against Strings but I can't seem to query against a number - what am I doing wrong here? What needs to be done differently from strings? Here's my code:

```
- (void)searchUsers {
//        NSDictionary *searchParameters = @{ @"where": @{@"objectId": @"2vQpRb6aF8"} };  //This works perfectly, because its a string I'm searching against in Parse
//        NSDictionary *searchParameters = @{ @"where": @{@"email": @"01000100.swan@gmail.com"} }; // Again, this works perfectly - also a string
//        NSDictionary *searchParameters = @{ @"where=": @{@"age": @{@"$gte" : @900}}}; // This doesn't work - it returns all values in the table with seemingly no filter against age, when there should be no results where "age" is greater than 900.

        NSDictionary *searchParameters = @{ @"where": @{@"age": [NSNumber numberWithInt:25]}};  // Again, this doesn't work. There should be 5 results where age = 25, and yet none are returned
//         @{ @"where": @{@"age": @{@"$gte" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:18]}}}

        [self.requestManager GET:@"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/userFromFB" parameters:searchParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Search Result: %@", [responseObject description]);
        }

        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        }];
}
```

Any help/pointers or even better examples of making queries against a number type on iOS would be hugely appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Have you tried sending a string with a number value instead? EG `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", someIntVariable]` instead of your `NSNumber`

Comment: Thanks, had tried that. Please see my answer below as to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was in the encoding of the query for Parse. When using the REST API with query constraints you have to encode/pass the constraints as JSON (so an NSDictionary then serialized as JSON) and THEN you have to encode that JSON with a URL encoding. I simply used: http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html#ad-output to encode the URL and made a GET request with that - worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Parse dashboard and confirm that the type for `age` is a Number. What data is displayed in the dashboard when you save `age` using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:25]`? You might be saving the data to Parse as an int but trying to retrieve it as an NSNumber.